# Setting a cookie in an Httpurlconnection Request

Tags: android, session-cookies, httpurlconnection

I want to set a cookie from a previous HTTPResponse in my HTTPRequest Header for authenfication.

I saved my cookie in a StringArray along with a JSONObject and the corresponding URL for the purpose of testing and transfer it to a AsyncTask.

Later i could realise it with cookiestore, sharedpreferences .... but for now my cookie is saved in postData[2].

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... postData)
{
    try 
    {

        URL url=new URL(String.valueOf(postData[1]));
        HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        httpsConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");

        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("cookie",postData[2]);

        httpsConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        httpsConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpsConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpsConnection.setUseCaches(false);


        postOut=new DataOutputStream(httpsConnection.getOutputStream());
        postOut.writeBytes(String.valueOf(postData[0]));
        postOut.flush();
        postOut.close();
    //.....
    //.....
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
}
```

The error msg is 
errors":[{"value":"","context":"","text":"Session is invalid.","contextPath":"","code":10101,"details":[],"contextObject":""}]

If i try this with Postman it works all fine, so my thought is that the cookie isnt correctly set?

Comment: What does postData[2] look like? It could be formatted incorrectly. It should be a string resembling "name=value".

Comment: Perfect example for: overlooking the smale pieces. Your thought was very valuable:)   Description of the solution: "nme=value" is not "name=value"